# How to skip intro on Counter Strike Condition Zero?

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

hi everybody could anyone help me about this problem:
I installed counter strike condition zero deleted scenes on my desktop computer; its specs:

processor intel(R) pentium(R) CPU 2.26 GHz
RAM 1 GB
Graphics card (integrated) 32 MB
os: windows xp sp2 32bit

the problem is: when I run the game I get the main menu so when I choose new game then eg: normal difficulty then the game starts to loading then it fails to start the game but it returns always to the main menu???!!
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your graphics card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnx guys I finally figured it out: I have just found a hl.reg and add it then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following allows you to skip to certain checkpoints or entire levels:

In half-life 1, a console command called `map name ca0a0` would bring you to the loading screen of Welcome to Black Mesa. ca0a1 would be after the tram I believe. Try typing `map name` and pressing tab to see what maps are available. The lower the hex values if any the closer to the beginning you will be.

Counter-Strike 1.5's console command to change levels which was ported to Condition Zero was `changelevel [mapnamehere]` so be sure to also keep that in mind as a possibility.

This is just a note from an old user of the first engine's console, it's not guarenteed, but since I know Deleted Scenes was built on the same engine then I know that Most of the same commands will work in it. (I.E. `sv_cheats 1` enables cheats and `impulse 101` gives you all weapons etc.)

If you wish to have hard facts I will update this with a list of console commands.

Some level names that may work are:

- Recoil (file name known as cz_recoil, [Source](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Recoil#Trivia))

  - Sample `changelevel cz_recoil` or `map cz_recoil`
- Lost Cause (possible to be known as lostcause but no confirmations yet)

  - Sample `changelevel lostcause` or `map lostcause`

*SIDEBAR*: Please note that if you're being bounced repeatily to the main menu and the console commands do not help, then it may be that the engine **cannot open your integrated video card**! Some cards have been known to not be able to run video games when they are integrated with your CPU. This is because some if not most integrated chips before the Core 2 Duo series did not support DirectX or OpenGL. This made it somewhat impossible to render any game under those chips.

**TL;DR Sidebar** If your graphics card is integrated you may not be able to play most games that require rendering of graphics.